# php for each display only first row

Tags: php, datetime

I am using [Advanced Custom Fields](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/) to save an array of different dates for upcoming events.

I want to display only the next upcoming date. Currently I am trying:

```
<?php
$rows = get_field('si-termine' ); // get all the rows
foreach($rows as $row){
    //If the date is greater than the current time then return the row
    if(strtotime($row['si-datum'])>time())
    {
        $nextdate = $row['si-datum'];
        echo $nextdate;
    }
        //There are no dates that are yet to be completed
        echo "No upcoming events";
    }
?>
```

This code has two problems.

- First, because of `foreach` it loops through every date and displays *no upcoming events* for each date thats in the past. This should only be displayed if all dates lay in the past.
- Second if the next event is this evening (saved only by date (20160701) without time) its recognized as a already past date.

How can I fix these?

Comment: You need to select the correct rows from the database instead of getting all. Then you don't need any conditions in php.

Comment: What is the source of your input data?

Comment: I am using a `repeater field` in wordpress, in which I save a `date` field

[1] https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/repeater/
[2] https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/date-picker/

Comment: Regarding your second problem: what if the event was this morning, with your logic it would show a past event as upcoming?

Comment: What I mean is, you need the time

Comment: Not all of the dates got a certain time. Your example would not be stated as a problem by the client, as its more about informing of what they do. So it would be ok to show a morning date the whole day as next upcoming!